# Android notifications after "all app close" button

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I am using notifications in my application and everything works well - the notification is showing at desired time to me, even after device reboot.

However, when I click the special button to close all apps, so it closes my app, the notification is not showing at all.

"The special button to close all apps" - I mean the one where you can list all the background apps and then with one click kill them all.

I am testing everything on OnePlus 3T.

Is it possible to run the service again after that "kill all apps" click ?

manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    ...

        <receiver
            android:name="com.saga.thewitcherquotes.QuoteOfTheDayReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.saga.thewitcherquotes.DeviceBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.saga.thewitcherquotes.QuoteOfTheDayIntentService"
            android:exported="false"></service>
```

BootReceiver:

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            // on device boot compelete, reset the alarm
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, QuoteOfTheDayReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
            if(calendar.before(current))
            {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

The service with notification builder:

```
public class QuoteOfTheDayIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 3;


    public QuoteOfTheDayIntentService() {
        super("MyNewIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.quote_of_the_day));
        DatabaseHandler db = DatabaseHandler.getInstance(this);
        Random generator = new Random();
        int id = generator.nextInt(db.getQuotesSize());
        Quote quote = db.getQuote(id, null);
        builder.setContentText(quote.getQuote());
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.swords);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notifyIntent.putExtra("id",id-1);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notificationCompat = builder.build();
        NotificationManagerCompat managerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        managerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationCompat);
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your notification builder?

Comment: What type of service are you using? Service or intent service???

Comment: IntentService, sorry that I forgot to add it earlier.